# Mockito flutter error: Cannot retrieve modification time

Tags: flutter, dart, mockito

To prepare mockito Mocks for test, my use case:

```
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:.../repositories/random_activity_repository.dart';

@GenerateMocks([RandomActivityRepository])
void main() {}
```

When I build with: `flutter packages pub run build_runner`
Something goes wrong, and for every file I have, I get:

`FileSystemException(path:...dart,  message=Cannot retrieve modification time) [SEVERE]`

I am tired of reading the docs (here: https://pub.dev/packages/mockito and here: https://github.com/mockito/mockito) but I cannot find this kind of error.

Can somebody help me UNDERSTAND what's going on?

Comment: Build systems often check file modification times to determine if generated files are stale and need to be rebuilt (i.e., they're older than the source files they were generated from).  This won't work if they can't retrieve modification times.  What is your operating system and what is the file system that the files reside on?  Is there anything unusual about it (such as it being a network share)?  Does your user have read permission to those files and to the directory they're in?

Comment: i use macBookPro 2019 intel, work give me. i just re-created project and give me same problem, i dont know some actions to avoid this problem :(.

Comment: somebody can help me please?

Comment: You didn't really answer my questions.  There's something quite unusual about your environment that prevents reading file modification times, but you haven't provided any hints about what.  You alternatively could try using [`package:mocktail`](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail), which does not depend on code generation.

Comment: You also could show some evidence that your user *can* access the modification times of those same files by other means, which would indicate that there's a bug in the Dart runtime.  Otherwise it sounds like a system configuration problem, not a programming problem, and maybe would be better answered on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: :( i canti really answer you about system configurations :(... first i will try with package: mocktail... thakYouuu i will update here :)

Comment: YOU have reason... is my laptop of work with some limitations (like encrypt or similar) escuse me if dont answer before :=) thankYouuu